# Fill Pick List Dynamically from contact

Tags: object, dynamic, salesforce, picklist

I'm a newbie, I want to add a picklist to a custom object. I want to populate the picklist with first & last names from contacts.

Please let me know what is the best practice / approach and how to achieve this.

Is it possible to do this in the existing edit page of the custom object?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Picklists don't work that way, nor should they -- what happens if you have 1000 contacts?  They can't possibly all fit in a single dropdown list.

Instead you should make a custom Lookup Relationship field (or even a Master-Detail, have a look at the docs to learn the differences between those, but they're similar) on your custom object that looks up to Contact.  Admittedly it won't be as quick to use as a picklist would be, but it's much more scalable.

Comment: thanks for your reply. 

I have a custom field in the Contacts and i'll filter by that field. so the max number of contacts i'm expecting is about 30 to 40.

I tried the custom lookup relationship, but i'd expect the contacts (filtered) would be listed in the search results.

But the requirement is also to have a dropdown (picklist).